# Customizing Layer Display in Map based on Nested Criteria selection with dropdown field outside the Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet, maps

I have about 5 different polygon map layers on a map. Each map layer data is stored as separate JSON file (Eg: continent1.json, continent2.json, ...... continent5.json). Every layer have its own different properties (Eg: Each continent layer contains different country's boundaries and feature details like country name, country type etc). These Continent Layer files are fetched dynamically and gets displayed on the map based on the continent name which i select from a dropdown input field placed outside the map (Eg: If i select continent1 from the dropdown field, then it will display continent1.json layer and it have popup feature display, highlight onmouseover, click zoom events for each country when hovering over the countries of that continent layer.) Upto this, my code is working perfectly.

Now I have one more child dropdown field outside the map having some value that are stored and fetched from database . (Eg: If i select continent1 layer from the first dropdown field it will display continent1 layer on map and it will show the type name of countries such as Developed Countries, Developing Countries, Poor Countries etc in the second dropdown input field. That type names are stored in database and fetched according to the continent selected from parent dropdown input field). My requirement is to display the boundaries of selected type of countries only rather than displaying all types of countries in that continent. Is there any simple method to achieve this requirement?

My code is as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="continent" name="continent" onChange="change_countrytype();">
    <option value="asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
  </select>
  <select id="countrytype" name="countrytype" style="width:100%">
  </select>
<script>
function change_countrytype()
    {
       var continent = $("#continent").val();
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/countrytype.php", //countrytype.php lists data fetched from DB.
        data: "continent="+continent,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
            {
                $("#countrytype").html(response);
            }
            });
            var layerName1=continent;   
            if(continent!='')
            {   
                loadContinent(layerName1);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please select Continent");  
            }
    }
</script> 
  <input type="text" name="countryname" id="countryname">
  <input type="button" id="searchcountry" value="Search" />
  <div id="map" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>

<script>
//BASE LAYER DISPLAY
        const mbAttr = '';  
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    const streets        = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr}),
        sattelite        = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/satellite-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr})
    ;
    const map = L.map("map", {
        center: [8.4819, 77.0361],
        zoom: 8, 
        layers: [streets]
        });                 
    var baseLayers = {
        "Streets": streets, 
        "Sattelite": sattelite,         
    };
    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent;
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent = feature.properties.popupContent;
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }  

//LAYER STYLE
var ConOptions = {
        fillColor: '#FFFF00',
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#FFFF00',
        dashArray: 3,
        fillOpacity: 0.2}; 

//HIGHLIGHT LAYER DIVISION
    function highlightFeature(e) {      
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 4,
            color: '#000',
            fillOpacity: 0.4
        });
        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

//ZOOM TO LAYER DIVISION    
    function zoomToFeature(e) { map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds()); }     
//LAYER FILE FETCH        
      async function getGeojson1(layerName1) 
      {
        const response1 = await fetch(`${layerName1}.json`);
        const geojson1 = await response1.json();
        return geojson1;
      }  

//LAYERS DISPLAY      
      const layerCaching1 = {};
      const currentDisplayedLayer1 = {};      
      const clearMap1 = () => {
        Object.keys(currentDisplayedLayer1).forEach((layer1) => {
          map.removeLayer(currentDisplayedLayer1[layer1]);
          delete currentDisplayedLayer1[layer1];
        });
      };
      const loadContinent = async (layerName1) => 
      {
      if (layerName1 === "") { return clearMap1(); }
      let geojson1;
      if (!layerCaching1[layerName1]) 
      {  
      const geojsonData1 = await getGeojson1(layerName1);           
      geojson1 = L.geoJSON([geojsonData1], {style: function (feature) { return conOptions; }, 
      onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) 
      {  
      popupOptions = {maxWidth: 450};
      layer.on({ mouseover: highlightFeature, mouseout: resetHighlight, click: zoomToFeature });
      layer.bindPopup("<b>Continent Name: </b>" + feature.properties.CONTINENT +
                    "<br><b>Country Name: </b>" + feature.properties.COUNTRY +
                    "<br><b>Country Type: </b>" + feature.properties.TYPE
                    ,popupOptions);
      }
      });   

      $('#searchcountry').click(function() 
      {    
        var countrytype = $('#countrytype').val();  
        var countryname = $('#countryname').val();
        if(countrytype!='')
          {
            if(countryname!='')
            {
                alert(countryname); // Here instead of alerting country name, i want to highlight and zoom to the particular country name.
            }
            else
            {
                alert ('Please enter Country Name');    
            }
          }
        else
          {
            alert ('Please select Country Type');   
          }
      }); 
    
      } 
      else 
      geojson1 = layerCaching1[layerName1];
      if (Object.keys(currentDisplayedLayer1).length > 0) 
      clearMap1();
      currentDisplayedLayer1[layerName1] = geojson1;
      if (!layerCaching1[layerName1]) 
      layerCaching1[layerName1] = geojson1;
      currentDisplayedLayer1[layerName1].addTo(map); 
    };    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[See my working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizing-layer-display-in-map-based-on-nested-criteria-selection-with-dropdown-field-outside-the-map-fknmy?file=/index.html)

Comment: I know the question is bit confusing and little hard to explain. So i am just trying to say it in a simple way. When i select Asia from continent dropdown field, it has to dynamically fetch & display asia.json layer file in map (Upto this, it is working). Now if i select India from another dropdown field it has to remove all other countries boundaries (countries have state boundaries inside it too) in that Asia layer and display India's boundary and its state boundaries only. Again if i input Delhi inside a textbox & click search button, it has to zoom and highlight to Delhi state of India.

Comment: Would be nice if you could isolate the client side part and create a demo with a mock response that you get from your backend to be able to play with.

Comment: @kboul, I had updated the question with my working demo. Please check. Also check the JSON Layer features. Each JSON layer file have details about a Continent containing the boundaries of countries in that continent, type of the country and country number. Country type may be same of different for each continent. Country number also may be same or different for each different country type or countries in different continent.

Comment: I would follow a different approach based on the new given requirements. Now things are a bit more complex and I am not sure if you need to cache only 3 jsons. You can just import them via es6 `import`. I thought you had several jsons. You need to filter and break the regions to show based on the type selection into smaller geojsons ,store them into variables, so to be able to directly toggle them on the map. Otherwise filtering always by switching layers is going to be an expensive operation. Also please ask the second question (input text field with the country name) on a separate thread.

Comment: @kboul, i had modified my demo to make my requirement working now. Just repeated the async functions to get the required output. but i dont know whether its the correct method of implementation for my requirement. Anyway i had one more small requirement. When i search a country number it gets highlighted and zoomed to that polygon. And i want to turn on the popup automatically rather than click trigger. i tried openPopup() but not working.